# Prolog program to determine if two numbers are amicable

Tags: prolog

`Amicable(x,y)`

Return true or false

```
Divisor(N,Divisor) :-
   Upperbound is round(sqrt(n),
   between(1,Upperbound, D),
   0 is N mod D

Properdivisor(N,D) :-
   divisor(N,D),
   D=/= N.
```

Comment: Does `0 is N mod D` have something after it? Is a `.` missing?

Comment: Is `round(sqrt(n)` missing a `)`?

Comment: Predicate names must start with lower case letters (unless quoted).

Comment: The `n` in `sqrt(n)` needs to be capitalized, so would the `x` and `y` in the amicable predicate.

Comment: `Divisor(N,Divisor)` you aren't using `Divisor` as a variable in the body of the predicate, you are using `D`. That probably needs to match the parameter name.